# Android com.androidnetworking.common does not exist

Tags: android, rx-java2

I have issue with Rx2 Networking is not working. I have already added RXjava dependency in Gradle file but still getting this below error.

"error: package com.rx2androidnetworking does not exist
import com.rx2androidnetworking.Rx2AndroidNetworking "

Comment: You probably also need to add the dependency for that networking library: https://github.com/amitshekhariitbhu/Fast-Android-Networking#using-fast-android-networking-library-in-your-application

Comment: @akarnokd i alredy added this dependency. but still getting error.

Comment: Maybe you added it to the wrong gradle file? Did you refresh gradle? Perhaps clear caches in your IDE?